# Appending a textarea to another textarea on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to create a Medium-esque project where pressing enter in a textarea will create another textarea after it.

I've tried using jQuery with append() and html() but neither have been succesful.

This is the method I currently have:

```
  $('textarea').keypress(function(event)
  {
      if (event.keyCode == 13)
      {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('textarea').append("<textarea>New Textarea</textarea>");
      }
  });
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `$('textarea')` selects all textarea elements, which is fine for setting up the event, but within the event you need to select the particular element associated with the event instead of selecting all of the textareas again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$("textarea").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).after("<textarea>New Textarea</textarea>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! Do you know how I'd go about shifting the focus the new textarea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `on` `keypress` event so that the appended `textarea` will also have that event. Use `after` to append HTML elements after.

```js
$('body').on('keypress', 'textarea', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).after("<textarea>New Textarea</textarea>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>New Textarea</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `insertAfter` instead of `append`

```
$('<textarea>New Textarea</textarea>').insertAfter(this);
```